# What happened to package hardening-includes in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I need to install hardening-check on Ubuntu 17.04. Until 16.10, it was available in the [package hardening-includes](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=hardening-includes&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Any idea what happened to the package and how I can install hardening-check?

Answer (score 3):

You can always find what happened to a package by looking at [its publishing history on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hardening-wrapper/+publishinghistory):

> Removal requested on 2016-10-19.
>   Deleted on 2016-10-19 by Matthias Klose
>   lp: [#1620313](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1620313): remove hardening-wrapper in zesty

And bug 1620313 says:

> stop using hardening-wrapper, obsoleted by recent dpkg-dev

So, it's apparently obsolete.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Hardening#hardening-wrapper

Comment: Does this mean the tool hardening-check is not available any more because they don't need it for DEB packages any more? Unfortunate, since I need it for other software projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can install this package from 16.10 version by the link https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/hardening-includes_2.8+nmu3ubuntu1_all.deb

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and above, `hardening-check` is included in the package `devscripts`: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/hardening-check.1.html